# const String vs. String in method call

Tags: string, visual-c++, c++-cli, constants

In trying to learn C++/CLI Microsoft Windows UI applications I am puzzled by an error I am getting.

I have defined one of the class members of `MyForm` as,

```
const String ^ SAMPLE_TEXT = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Praesent et nunc at erat commodo placerat.";
```

In the method,

```
System::Void MyForm_Paint(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e)
```

the compiler gives an error when the function,

`e->Graphics->DrawString(SAMPLE_TEXT, the_font, blackBrush, *rect);`

is called, the error being,

`error C2664: 'void System::Drawing::Graphics::DrawString(System::String ^,System::Drawing::Font ^,System::Drawing::Brush ^,System::Drawing::RectangleF,System::Drawing::StringFormat ^)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const System::String ^' to 'System::String ^'`

I am surprised that `DrawString` will not accept a `const String`.  That is, I **want** the `String` contents to be constant, not caring that the pointer itself is variable.  As I understand it, the qualifier `const` applies to whatever is to its immediate right.

The program will compile and run if I leave off the `const` in the definition of `SAMPLE_TEXT`.  Also, writing it as,

```
String ^ const SAMPLE_TEXT = "Lorem ipsum dolor...";
```

will compile and run.  However, I understand this to mean a **constant pointer** to text which can be changed, not what I want.

This is all being done in Visual Studio 2015.

Shouldn't I be able to specify a `String` the contents of which cannot be changed by the program and have a function use it?

Comment: The *const* keyword only means something in the C and C++ languages, other languages that run on the CLR (like C#, VB.NET, F#, etc) have no equivalent.  The CLR cannot enforce it and the .NET Framework does not use *const* in the declaration of its methods.  Graphics::DrawString() does not, as you can tell from the error message.  As far as the C++/CLI compiler knows the method *might* alter the string content.  So it complains.  So you can't use it.  Nothing lost, System::String is already immutable by convention.

Comment: Hans, Thanks.  Never crossed my mind that `const` would not have carried over.  Based on your answer I did some digging in another direction and found that C++/CLI uses `literal` for what I had in mind meaning roughly the equivalent of `static const`.